# Anchor events in listview and iframe (jquery mobile)

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, iframe

I cannot make this easy thing to work properly.

I have basically a lot of `<a>` elements made in this way:

`<a href="$here_the_link" class="details poppingup" target="framepopup">mytext</a>`

What I want to achieve is that clicking on a link made like this (with `target`equal to that frame and having the class `poppingup`) makes a popup open with the iframe inside.

The popup/iframe code follows:

```
<div data-role="popup" id="popup">
   <iframe src="#" width="497" height="298" id="framepopup" name="framepopup" seamless></iframe>
</div>
```

And I have a javascript ran when the `mobileinit` event is fired:

```
$("[data-role='content']").on('click', 'a.poppingup', function(e) {
  console.log("opening the popup for " + $(this).attr('href'));
  $("#popup").popup("open");
});
```

**THE RESULT:** if I click on a link everywhere in the page, this works fine.
But if I click on a link **inside a listview**, the code is executed (i can see the console message and the popup opening for 1 second) BUT then the browser moves to the page that I wanted to display in the iframe.

So I've tried to add this code:

```
$("[data-role='listview']").on('click', 'a.poppingup', function(e) {
    console.log("opening the popup for " + $(this).attr('href'));

    //$("#framepopup").attr('src', $(this).attr('href'));
    $("#popup").popup("open");
    e.preventDefault();
    e.stopPropagation(); 
  });
```

Like this the window doesn't move from the page, I see the popup but the popup is empty.
If I decomment the line where I set the 'src', the window moves to the page with url `$(this).attr('href')`.

Any help is really appreciated!

**EDIT:**
Thanks to Omar we found out that it's a problem completely related to the target website...

Comment: All you need is `e.preventDefault()`.

Comment: Hi @Omar as you can see I've already tried with `preventDefault()`. It's true that I didn't mention that I've tried both `preventDefault()` and `stopPropagation()` in the `$("[data-role='content']").on('click')`callback, if this is what you mean

Comment: `$("[data-role='listview']").on('click', 'a.poppingup', function(e) { e.preventDefault(); console.log("opening the popup for " + $(this).attr('href')); $("#popup").popup("open"); });` try this.

Comment: It opens the popup but the content of the popup (the iframe) is not updated

Comment: because you didn't update `iframe` url. `var iframe = $(this).attr('href');` and then update iframe src `$("#popup iframe").prop("src", iframe);` finally open popup `$("#popup").popup("open");`; or open popup and then update iframe's src. check code here http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/RDKJM/

Comment: @Omar yes but that's the point, if I update the iframe src, I have the described behavior. ONLY if the 'click' event is fired inside a listview.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44396/discussion-between-omar-and-lorenzo-s)